# Checking Response from php curl_exec()?

Tags: php, curl

I have the following cUrl function call that is returning the response code.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I need to check the $result for the following response property.

```
   <isValidPost>true</isValidPost>
```

I could always parse through and  check for that exact string, but is there an alternative way to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that the API is set in stone (i.e. won't change at a moment's notice), in this case it's probably safe to a simple string search

```
if (false !== strpos($result, '<isValidPost>true</isValidPost>')) {
```

However, to do this in a more reliable way, you may want to do DOM parsing:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->parseXML($result);
$isValidPostTag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('isValidPost')->item(0);
if ($isValidPostTag) {
    $isValidPost = $isValidPostTag->nodeValue == 'true';
} else {
    $isValidPost = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting XML response? Then parse the XML

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
if(isset($xml->your_element->isValidPost)){
   //do what you need
}
```